# Update Material UI DataGrid row via Dialog Popup with Edit-Form in Material UI V5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I have Material UI DataGrid table with an Action column which contains an edit button per row.

**How is it possible to update a DataGrid row through a Dialog Popup with an Edit-Form that opens when the Edit Button of a row is clicked, rather than through inline Row-Editing?**

I cannot find any example. Any Link to some example or documentation appreciated

Basically, I think this should work via renderCell section in the columns definition where the current row data needs to be passed to the dialog which contains the EditForm.

Cannot find any working example or documentation with the latest Material UI version (V5.11 community edition)